# Perl looping through a hash produces strange value

Tags: perl

I'm using Perl to parse the output from `objdump`. I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

%count = {};

while (<>) {
 if (/^\s+[[:xdigit:]]+:\s+[[:xdigit:]]+\s+([a-z]+).+$/) {
  ++$count{"$1"};
 }
}

while (($key, $val) = each %count) {
 print "$key $val\n";
}
```

In the resulting output, most parts are okay like this:

```
strhib 2
strcc 167
stmlsda 4
swivc 21
ldmlsia 4
```

But there is one strange line:

```
HASH(0x8ae2158)
```

What's going on here? I expect `$1` to be a string, and `++$count{"$1"}` should be perfectly fine.

Thank you.

So the correct code should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %count;

while (<>) {
 if (/^\s+[[:xdigit:]]+:\s+[[:xdigit:]]+\s+([a-z]+).+$/) {
  ++$count{"$1"};
 }
}

while (my ($key, $val) = each %count) {
 print "$key $val\n";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you had `use warnings;` you would have seen: "Reference found where even-sized list expected".  Instead of

```
%count = {};
```

you should have said

```
my %count;
```

What you wrote was equivalent to this:

```
%count = ({} => undef);
```

That is, you initialized your hash with an empty hashref as a key with no associated value.  The hashref stringified to "HASH(0x8ae2158)" (the number may change).  To clear out a hash, you use parens `()` not braces `{}`.  Braces construct a hash reference.

Even short programs like this should start with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

The bugs you catch will be your own. :-)

The [warnings](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?warnings) pragma is preferred to the `-w` switch because it acts lexically.  See [What's wrong with `-w` and `$^W`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html#What%27s-wrong-with-%2a-w%2a-and-%24%5eW) in [perllexwarn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html).

Comment: Thank you! I even forgot the `use strict`.

Comment: `use strict` (while a good idea) won't catch this particular error.  But `use warnings` will.

Comment: Then between using `perl -w` in the shebang, and `use` ing it, which is the better practice?

Comment: `use warnings` is more useful because it's lexically scoped (so you can turn it off at the block-level when you need to do otherwise warning-generating things). But `-w` is certainly fine for one-liners.